# Vaxhall Astra H 1.9 150PS it stops in the middle of the road by pressing the gas pedal

Tags: troubleshooting, astra

I have an Astra H 1.9 150ps.

During driving when I press the gas pedal to increase the speed of vehicle it stops in the middle of the road, my auto shuts down.

This problem is present just when I push the gas pedal to increase speed.

The problem first appeared in high gears(3,4) and faster speeds (like 70-90 mph), now it is happening in the lower gears 2,3 and 4.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what happens? Can you restart the engine immediately with the starter motor, or do you have to push the car to the side of the road and wait 20 minutes? Does it happen when you have just got in the car? Or after driving for some time? or completely randomly?

Comment: Do you have an automatic transmission?

Comment: Yes i can restart it in 10 seconds

Comment: When this problem appears I can turn the auto on well in 10 sec without going to the side of road, i do it by driving so in middle of road

Comment: No i have an manual transmission

Comment: I have testet the EGR , it is ok